# How to remove Google Adwords gclid Query String in .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, google-analytics, google-ads-api

I tried these examples:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^gclid=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^(.*)?gclid=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1?gclid=%2 [QSA,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(gclid=.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/ [L,PT]
```